# stop/cancel ScheduledFuture

Tags: java, spring, scheduling

I am able to call the `start()` function to run this Quarterly Metric Report Scheduling Service that implements Runnable to schedule a certain task, but I also need to be able to stop/cancel the scheduled tasks later in case I need to change the schedule time.

I have read many posts and tried several ways to make the `stop()` function work, but no luck.
I guess my question can also be how can i find/retrieve the scheduled tasks and cancel them?

Would someone please help? Thanks a lot.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableScheduling
    public class QuarterlyMetricReportScheduling{

        @Autowired
        QuarterlyMetricReportService qmrService;

        ScheduledFuture sf;

        CronTrigger trigger;

        int shutdownTimeout = 1 * 60 * 1000;//10 sec

        @Autowired
        QuarterlyMetricReportSchedulingService task;

        public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
            ThreadPoolTaskScheduler tps = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        tps.setThreadNamePrefix("job");
        return tps;
        }

        public void changeTrigger(String cronExpression){
        System.out.println("change trigger to: " + cronExpression);
        trigger = new CronTrigger(cronExpression);
        start();
        }

        public void start(){

        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler  tps = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        tps.initialize();
        task = new QuarterlyMetricReportSchedulingService();
        tps.schedule(task, trigger);
        }

        public void stop() {

        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler tps = threadPoolTaskScheduler();
        //tps = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        //tps.setThreadNamePrefix("job");
        tps.initialize();
            task = new QuarterlyMetricReportSchedulingService();
        trigger = new CronTrigger("0 59 11 26 3 ?");
        tps.schedule(task, trigger);
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = tps.getScheduledExecutor();
            try {
            //ScheduledServiceExecutor service = 
                //Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            task = new QuarterlyMetricReportSchedulingService();
            ScheduledFuture future = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
            task, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

            future.cancel(true);
            scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
            }


    }
```

Comment: `10 seconds` is given as `10 * 1000` not `10 * 60 * 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bit strange that you only schedule your task in the stop method.

You need to schedule the task at start, keep the future as a handle, and then call cancel on the future in the stop method.

You should create a thread pool once and use it for all reports, otherwise there is no pooling.